# What is the ability Flash about?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I am having [Nephalia Seakite](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Nephalia%20Seakite) in my deck, and it has Flash.

I read from [MTG Salvation](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Flash) that "Flash is a keyword ability which allows cards to be played at any time you could play an Instant."

But I am not understanding, what I am reading.
Does Seakite's skill give me a chance to summon whatever I like (as long as the Mana meets), whenever I like, for as long as it stays in the battlefield?

As an example: With this skill, can I summon a creature of my own in the middle of my opponent's turn?

Comment: You linked to the page that had the rules for Flash. That would have answered your question.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Yes, it had the answer, but it didn't have it as in an understandable form. In other ways, I didn't understand what I was reading.

Comment: @Damaskox I agree that the wiki wording is confusing and unclear. Shame on them. However, the actual comprehensive rule is shown on that page, too, and it is quite explicit and clear: *Flash is a static ability that functions in any zone from which you could play the card it’s on. "Flash" means "You may play this card any time you could cast an instant."*

Comment: @ghoppe Okay, but I will still stay in my statement.

Comment: @Damaskox I downvoted because you keep repeating *"I am confused."* without explaining what you are confused *about*. If you add an explanation of how rule 702.8 is confusing for you, then I'll consider retracting my vote. This isn't just to make me feel good - knowing why you are confused can help people provide a better answer.

Comment: @Rainbolt it's quite clear where his confusion is. You and I know flash means "you can play this card at instant speed", but he is reading it to mean "you can play any creature at instant speed while this card is on the battlefield", which is a not-completely-crazy interpretation of the wiki text.

Comment: @Rainbolt Yes, but not just "any creature". Originally I thought it's about any card you have on your hand.
But now I know, what this means. Thank you.

Comment: @corsiKa I would agree if I had only read the question. However, in the comments (which you apparently read too) he acknowledged that he was still confused after reading the comprehensive rule. The rule literally says **"the card it’s on"**. How could that possibly be confusing? Is this question useful to anyone who has good command of the English language? I think not, and so I downvoted.

Comment: You're a developer, are you honestly going to say you've never read documentation that spelled things out perfectly but you were still confused afterward? It happens sometimes. And honestly, a lot of people mentally tense up when they get to the CR. They assume it's so complicated they could never really understand it. In any case, it isn't prudent to downvote a question based on comments. Comments are second class citizens on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @corsiKa There is a contradiction in your comment. If documentation was spelled out perfectly, I couldn't possibly be confused by it. Exaggerations like that only serve to start pointless arguments in the comments. I merely explained my downvote, but I didn't expect that I would have to start defending it. Also, [I don't think you get to decide what material is applicable to my downvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224565/254466). Comments are fair game. If you disagree, go post your own dissenting answer on that meta post. Enlighten us on how we should be voting.

Comment: You're right, I don't get to decide what you can and can't downvote. But that doesn't mean that your arguments for why you chose to downvote are logically sound (not that they need to be, granted) and actually you could construct a reasoned argument why given your stated reasons your downvote is actually unethical. Strange, but true. It is far beyond the scope of this comment, so we'll have to agree to disagree, but I really think you should do some soulsearching on it. Or not. I'm not a cop.

Comment: How about this: I downvoted this question because it links to a complete, canonical answer without any explanation of why that answer was not understood. The comments appear to indicate that the asker did not even read the page they linked to, indicating a profound lack of research effort, which is a perfectly valid downvote reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword ability *Flash* only applies to the card which has it.

So yes, you could play Nephalia Seakite during your opponent's turn. It doesn't apply to any other card unless that card also has *Flash*.

Answer (score 7):

Flash allows the card that has flash to be played at any time you could play an instant. It does not allow you to play any other cards at any time you have an instant. So Flash doesn't mean anything once it's on the battlefield. The actual rule:

> 702.8a Flash is a static ability that functions in any zone from which you could play the card it’s on. "Flash" means "You may play this card any time you could cast an instant."

You can summon a creature that has flash during your opponent's turn; just like you can cast an instant during your opponent's turn.

For example, you could wait for your opponent to attack you with his 2/2, cast [Nephalia Seakite](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Nephalia%20Seakite) at the end of his Declare Attackers Step (on his turn), then block the attacker with the Seakite to destroy the attacker. Only the Seakite can be cast as an instant (unless you have another card with Flash), and once the Seakite is on the battlefield, its Flash has no effect.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out the reminder text for Flash says "this spell", too, not spells in general.